# How to fetch a number from a file and assign it to a variable

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file which contains html response code as shown below:

```
<d:ChangeType>SSCR</d:ChangeType>
<d:Status>Success</d:Status>
<d:ShortDescription>API </d:ShortDescription>
<d:CycleTypeId>8000006005</d:CycleTypeId>
<d:RfcNumber>1200000910</d:RfcNumber>
<d:ExtrefNumber>API External</d:ExtrefNumber>
```

Requirement is to fetch number between `<d:RfcNumber>` and `</d:RfcNumber>` i.e.`1200000910` in this example and feed it to a variable.

I'm trying to use sed like:

```
sed 's/1200000910.*//' test2.html
```

but it is not providing me the expected result.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Bash or Powershell?

Comment: shell task in azure pipelines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Since you are using `sed` assuming you are using shell here. You could use `awk` command here. Simply using `awk` and setting field delimiter(s) as `<d:RfcNumber>` and `<\\/d:RfcNumber>` for all lines. In main program checking if number of fields are greater than 2 then printing the 2nd field.

```bash
var=$(awk -F'<d:RfcNumber>|<\\/d:RfcNumber>' 'NF>2{print $2;exit}' Input_file)
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk`'s `match` function here to get values between tags.

```bash
var=$(awk 'match($0,/^<d:RfcNumber>([^<]*)<\/d:RfcNumber>/,arr){print arr[1];exit}' Input_file)
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** OR with `sed` please try following code, with using `-E` option of GNU `sed` to use ERE(extended regular expression) in code.

```bash
var=$(sed -E -n 's/^<d:RfcNumber>([^<]*)<\/d:RfcNumber>/\1/p' Input_file)
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried with 3rd solution and it worked for me. :)

Comment: @gauravsharma the first solution is better in every way, did it not work for you? If not - what was the result of trying to use it?

Comment: @Ravinder `-F '<d:RfcNumber>|<\\/d:RfcNumber>'` = `-F '</?d:RfcNumber>'`. In addition to getting rid of all of the duplication, there's no need to escape `/` in a regexp unless it's being used within `/` delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

...the split way:

```
#Read your file content
$response = (gc C:\tmp\testdata.txt)
$rfc = ($response -split "<d:RfcNumber>|</d:RfcNumber>")[5]
```

or regex (but this could probably be optimized):

```
#Read your file content
$response = (gc C:\tmp\testdata.txt)
($response | select-string "<d:RfcNumber>\d{10}").matches.groups.value -replace "<d:RfcNumber>"
```

or you use it as xml:

```
[xml]$xml = '<root>' + (($response -replace "d:") -join $null) + '</root>'
$xml.root.RfcNumber
```

Comment: Thank you Toni. Your answer worked for me if I change the task to powershell.

Comment: indeed you did not use powershell :-) I did probably filter the questions wrong... but nice that you verified it.... sstay strong azure is a pain ;-)